# The argument type 'Future<SharedPreferences>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'SharedPreferences'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sharedpreference

I want to access the shared preferences at the application startup and want to use this same object across the entire app by passing it to the classes. I am getting the following error:

> The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the
> parameter type 'SharedPreferences'.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:application/layouts/ScreenOne.dart';
import 'package:application/layouts/ScreenTwo.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  sharedPreferences() async {
    return await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  final preferences = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: (preferences.getInt("login") == 1 ? ScreenOne(preferences) : ScreenTwo(preferences)),
    );
  }

}
```

I am unable to resolve this error. Is there anything I am doing wrong or missing? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you defined function `sharedPreferences()` but did not use it later in the code - simply remove it.

Furthermore, based on the documentation `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` returns `Future<SharedPreferences>` and not `SharedPreferences`, hence you get the following error. You can resolve the issue by getting the `SharedPreferences` instance in the main method and then using constructor injection to provide the `preferences` object to the `MyApp`:

```
Future<void> main() async { // <-- Notice the updated return type and async
  final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); // <-- Get SharedPreferences instance
  
  runApp(
    MyApp(preferences: preferences), // <-- Inject (pass) SharedPreferences object to MyApp
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final SharedPreferences preferences;
  
  const MyApp({
    required this.preferences,
  })

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: (preferences.getInt("login") == 1 ? ScreenOne(preferences) : ScreenTwo(preferences)),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, so, this `preferences`, I will also be able to pass and use across the app classes, right?

Comment: Not really, you should specifically provide the `preferences` to your Widget tree by using [InheritedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) or third-party packages like [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider). Also, there is some info on [what to do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Could you please help me to know how to create the playground for receiving the same `preferences` in class also? Or how to get the `preferences` in the other screen?

Comment: This is a completely different question than the original one. If you have follow-up questions, do not start a thread in the comments and please create a new question in Stack Overflow - more people could help you this way.